# NextJS dev server response time

Tags: next.js, graphql

My main question is; is there a difference in response time for fetching in localhost vs live/production?

I have a project im building in NextJS, with GraphCMS and I'm using GraphQL/graphql-request to fetch the data. When I first start up localhost and the pages loads, I click a link in the page navigation to go to `about` page and it literally takes 2 seconds for the data to fetch and the page to change. I'm watching the network tab in Chrome DevTools and the `.json` file status is `(pending)` and then switches to `200` once the content is downloaded. Here is a screenshot from DevTools:

[image]

When I hover over the waterfall, It says the `Waiting for server response` is 1.86s and content download is 0.46ms. So is the waiting for server response, something because im on a localhost, or is this something to do with the GraphCMS server were its fetching the data from?

Also you may note that the json file size is only 5.2kB, so its not a large fetch.

To give you a little context on the code, my queries & client are stored in the `/lib` folder:

```
// /lib/client.js
import { GraphQLClient } from 'graphql-request'

export const graphcmsClient = () =>
  new GraphQLClient(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHCMS_URL, {
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.GRAPHCMS_TOKEN}`,
    },
  })

// example of a query in ./lib/queries.js
import { gql } from 'graphql-request'
    
const blogPageQuery = gql`
  fragment BlogPostFields on BlogPost {
    id
    category
    content
    coverImage {
      id
      height
      url
      width
    }
    excerpt
    published
    slug
    title
   }
  `
```

and here is an example where im using `getStaticProps` and fetching the query data:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params, preview = false }) {
  const client = graphcmsClient(preview)
  const collectionCards = await getAllCollections()

  const { page, navigation } = await client.request(pageQuery, {
    slug: params.slug
  })

  if (!page) {
    return {
      notFound: true
    }
  }

  const parsedPageData = await parsePageData(page)

  return {
    props: {
      page: parsedPageData,
      navigation,
      collectionCards,
      preview
    },
    revalidate: 60
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing this in development (`next dev`) or production mode (`next build && next start`)? What does the `all.json` file refer to?

Comment: I was testing in `next dev` but last night I decided to deploy it on Vercel and give it a test and the response time was super fast, so I think I answered my question, its slower in development mode. But the `all.json` I guess is the output from my `client.request(pageQuery)`, cause it has all the query/json data in it, but I'm guessing nextjs or graphql auto-generates the all.json file.

Comment: this is similar to this question, but I haven't seen any solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73654036/next-dev-takes-1min-to-load-waiting-for-server-response

Comment: I found this github discussion on the next repo, where other people have similar problems. I'm facing the same issue too - for me `next dev` is slow, `next build && next start` is fast. 

I think this might be unrelated to GraphQL so you might want to update the title  to "dev server response time" @RobbieC https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17977